# how to addClass with same ID with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to `addClass()` with same anchor I trigger.
When I click anchor, all ID with same anchor would add new class.

In this case I use same ID to trigger, I know its not proper to do it. Is there any better way how to do similar thing to this work
Please if there any better solution would be appreciate, thank you

```js
$('.main a').click(function(e){
  var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
  $(anchor).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.content,
.indicator{
  margin-top: 30px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}

.indi{
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.box.active,
.indi.active{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <a href="#item1">item1</a>
  <a href="#item2">item2</a>
  <a href="#item3">item3</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div id='item1' class="box"></div>
  <div id='item2' class="box"></div>
  <div id='item3' class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="indicator">
  <div id='item1' class="indi"></div>
  <div id='item2' class="indi"></div>
  <div id='item3' class="indi"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain more.
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: **ids need to be unique** and that is why your code is not working - if you do a selector for an id, then you will only get the first item with that id (not all items with that id).  Use a class and a data attribute instead

Comment: I want to addClass that have same value with anchor when click the anchor, thats why I use ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTML5 anchor tags' href property can be ommitted, it's better to use data-attributes for this. And in CSS `cursor: pointer` if that's important for the user xp.

```
<div class="main">
    <a data-target="#item1" data-indi="item1">item1</a>
    <a data-target=".item2" data-indi="item2">item2</a>
    <a data-target="[data-id=item3]" data-indi="item3">item3</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="item1" class="box"></div>
    <div class="box item2"></div>
    <div class="box" data-id="item3"></div>
</div>
<div class="indicator">
    <div data-id="item1" class="indi"></div>
    <div data-id="item2" class="indi"></div>
    <div data-id="item3" class="indi"></div>
</div>
```

In js:

```
$('.main a[data-target]').click(function(e){
    var el = $(this),
        target = el.data('target'),
        indi = el.data('indi'),
        indiTarget = $('[data-id="'+indi+'"]');
    $(target).add(indiTarget).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

This way it's a little more flexible. Also easy to simplify/combine both `data-target` and `data-indi` into one selector. I just made some examples on the target selector hence they're separated in my example.

Comment: Yeah this one I use to be looking, I just didn't know how to get data attribute value and comparing with other data attribute if have same value. This way is good, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In html you really should have only 1 element with a specific ID. So you should use classes for selection.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/q3j30f04/3/

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <a href="#item1">item1</a>
  <a href="#item2">item2</a>
  <a href="#item3">item3</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="box item1"></div>
  <div class="box item2"></div>
  <div class="box item3"></div>
</div>

<div class="indicator">
  <div class="indi item1"></div>
  <div class="indi item2"></div>
  <div class="indi item3"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the js code (since the href contains #, we remove it and use that with a "." prefix, which search for that class. )

```
$('.main a').click(function(e){
  var anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/,'');
  $('.'+anchor).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```

Comment: yeah, this is almost what am looking, but we have to keep adding class with same ID. Thank for your suggestion

Comment: Why to add class? Element with class item1 is selected only when #item1 is clicked, so there is no need to add it to the element. Or do you mean the link clicked should get a class?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.main a').click(function(e){
  var anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace("#",".");
  $(anchor).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.content,
.indicator{
  margin-top: 30px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}

.indi{
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.box.active,
.indi.active{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <a href="#item1">item1</a>
  <a href="#item2">item2</a>
  <a href="#item3">item3</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="box item1"></div>
  <div class="box item2"></div>
  <div class="box item3"></div>
</div>

<div class="indicator">
  <div class="indi item1"></div>
  <div class="indi item2"></div>
  <div class="indi item3"></div>
</div>
```